# Windows 10 upgrade via KB3035583

Tags: windows-7, windows-10-upgrade

How can I upgrade my old computer to Windows 10?

Pentium Core2, 2GB ram, Foxconn P4M9007MB-8RS2H motherboard, 32-bit operating system, Windows Experience Index of 2 with Windows 7 Ultimate, detailed WEI:
- processor = 4.8
- ram = 4.8
- graphics = 2.0
- gaming graphics = 3.0
- primary hard drive = 7.1 (due to a recently installed ssd).

Microsoft's KB3035583 update advises that the machine has insufficient graphics capability. But the machine currently runs Windows 7 Ultimate fine.

The machine originally came with a XFX GeForce 8400GS graphics card, which was removed because of a hardware failure, and it now uses the motherboard's onboard graphics.

I have a newer machine that KB035583 approves of. Can I create an installation disc from the new machine and install the o/s on the old machine?

Comment: The requires to run Windows 10 are the same requirements to run Windows 8.1 not Windows 7.  It sounds like the machine you have is not compatible with Windows 10.  If that is the case then you will be unable to upgrade to Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified what graphics card you have. It may be possible to upgrade your computer's GPU. If this is the only thing Windows Update is complaining about, that may be sufficient. Windows 10 only requires a graphics card capable of running DirectX 9. You should not expect Windows 10 to install at all, no matter what you do with installation disks, until you meet the minimum requirements.

Note, though, with such an old, underpowered machine, you should not expect a particularly good experience. Your CPU is from 2006 and you are woefully low on RAM.

Subsequent to my answer, you added information about your motherboard. Your motherboard provides graphics using the VIA Chrome9 HC. According to [this article](http://www.notebookcheck.net/VIA-Chrome9-HC.3712.0.html) in Notebook Check, the performance of that graphics chip is about half that of the Intel GMA 950. Notebook Check claims this graphics chip is unsuited for even Windows Vista. It's not going to be sufficient to run Windows 10, as Microsoft tells you. However, you do have the possibility of buying a replacement graphics card, which should just about get you to the absolute minimum requirements.